Question about Numbers (combination) Numbers 1 to 9 odd and even numbers
First time posting.
I am trying to solve this problem.
Consider a collection of cards numbered from 1 to 9.
123456789
All nine cards are arranged in a row so that if the numbers are read from left to right, the odd numbers are in increasing order. The even-numbered cards can be in any order. An example is shown below.
184357269
(a) How many ways can this be done?
(b) How many ways can eight of these cards be selected and then arranged in a row so that the odd numbers are in increasing order?
For part (a),
I take the combo as follow
Odd numbers are fixed 1,3,5,7,9

If all even numbers are before 1, then before 3,then before 5 etx
Then 4! x 6

If 1 even number and 3 even numbers


3! x 6 x 4

If 2 evens and 2 evens

2! x 6 x 2
Am I correct?
For part 2, I am trying to work that out. Question

You are making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Simply pick the position of the $2$, then pick the position of the $4$, then the $6$ and lastly the $8$.  The remaining positions can only be filled in in a single way.  For part (2) consider breaking into cases based on if the unused card is even vs odd.
